# Hook to change display widget in facet api from template.php

Tags: hooks, search

In my site i have search api with one block facet option "Display widget" set to "Links with checkboxes"

[image: Add with checboxed option]

but now i want to change the value to "Links"

[image: Links option]

because when the website is displayed on a mobile device i need to change to this option value.

Is there a way to change this option through any hook or another way to get this accomplished?

Maybe put a hook in template.php is my closes approach.

Thanks :)

Comment: Just wondering, what about a JS solution?

Comment: @Lance yes that solution would be valid too :)

Answer (score -1):

Create another index and configure facet display differently